# Create a form inside AJAX success call back

Tags: jquery, forms, dynamic, callback, getjson

I am using getJSON to populate form elements inside function(data) {...} by concatenating html.

What is the best way to create dynamic HTML Form inside the success call back of getJSON.

I should be able to enable/show divs/UI elements based on button clicks in this form.

Thanks

Comment: Code snippets would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to create the dynamic content and show it in an Pop-up.
If u would explain a bit through code it would be nice and you will get a quicker response.

Comment: I am using getJSON to pre-populate form elements(disabled/read only) inside success call back. On button click, I should show couple other text inputs and buttons and enable all text inputs. Is popup best way ?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily create HTML using jQuery with the following pattern:

```
var successFunc = function(json) {
  form = $('<form>').attr('method', 'get');
  form.append($('<input>').attr({'type': 'text', 'val', 'jquery rocks'});
  form.appendTo(document.body);
}
```

Or more specifically:

```
//assume json = { resultDiv: '.myResultDiv', value: 'this is an input' };

$.ajax({ ...
  success: function(json) {
    form = $('<form>').attr('method', 'get');
    form.append($('<input>').attr({'type': 'text', 'val', json.value});
    form.appendTo($(json.resultDiv));
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!